# export Microsoft project plan (.mpp) file stored in a sharepoint library to an excel which is also stored in sharepoint library when plan is updated

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-library, ms-project, microsoft

I need help in creating a power automate flow to update an excel file stored in a sharepoint library with the data from a microsoft project plan (.mpp file) which is also stored in a sharepoint library.